# How do I get javascript to get a button to open another html page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, spring

```
     First I must apologize Halnex for calling you Helix this whole time. I attempted to try your code but I am not getting my submit page to show up and I’m not completely sure why. Note I just copied the source code of JQuery to a file inside of one of my folders inside the folder holding these html pages.

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <HEAD>
        <title>WELCOME TO MY FORM PAGE</title>
<link rel="stylesheet type="text/css" href="style/style.css"> 
            <script src="jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function (){

                $('#button1').click(function (){

                    $('#response').load('form_submit.html');    
                    });
                });
            </script>
    </HEAD>
<BODY>
```

just two text boxes nothing special.

## Registrations

Username: 
            password: 
            
I'm not sure if these two lines are correct. Should maybe the input line be wrapping the div or something crazy like that?

```
Maybe my issue is with my code on my file I’m trying to load (form_submit.html)? This is all I have on my form_submit.html file: Does this code below for the submission page look acceptable or could this be where I am failing?
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>User Submission Page</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        Here are the details of the submitted form:
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show us the whole HTML please?

Comment: It you want to go into another page just use in JS file // similar behavior as an HTTP redirect
window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com"); But if you want to read some server HTML from browser javascript it just impossible. This is base security..You can do call to some API get html data response and then do something with it. But it's just sounds not right.

Comment: Your js is simply submitting a form, not accessing another page.

Comment: Where is the submit button in your HTML?

Comment: It says `action="form_submit.html"` but HTML cannot process form data. You need a programming language like PHP.

Comment: just a suggestion, never use method GET with passwords, instead use method POST

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As previously said, your button is trying to submit a form. To load an html page on button click use this.

```
<input type="button" id="button1" value="Load HTML Page">

<div id="response"></div>
```

The jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#button1').click(function() {
        $('#response').load('test.html');
    });
});
```

Comment: Your form's action attribute is pointing to `form_submit.html` but HTML cannot process form data. You need a programming language like PHP to process the data and do something with it.

Comment: I am not actually processing I am using html5 sessionStorage to hold the values entered on a seperate html page "form_submit.html. Perhaps this functionality is no longer supported?

Comment: Part 1. Hi Halnex, I tried using your idea but now i get a java script error right on my jquery line at the top. maybe I didn't code it correctly let me share what I now have with you and the community. I wounder If I placed that div you suggested in the wrong place too. Please excuse my noobness I am trying to learn this fun stuff after all. :)

Comment: Create a new html file and test the code I provided, I'm sure it will work. Notice that I am loading a page called `test.html` so you can change that to load the page you want, like `form_submit.html`